# Python regex to get first occurance only from ecommerce data inside script tag

Tags: regex, django, python-3.x, scrapy

**I'm using this regular expresion to get data from an eCommerce website which has required data inside script tag**   - `"quantity":"(.*?)"`

This regular expression is giving me all the matches in the data.

I have tried many ways to construct it using non-greedy method but no luck. Which expression should I use to stop the search at the first match from the data?TIA

sample Script data :

```
 ({{ HOLIDAY","on_sale":false,"quantity":"214","original_price":35,"price":35,"category_path":["Mens","Tees"],"created":"2018-12-01","modified":"2018-12-20","colors":["BLACK"],"sizes":["S","M","L","XL","XXL"],"upcs":["00000000190235804075","00000000190235804082","00000000190235804099","00000000190235804105","00000000190235804112"],"variations":[{"upc":"00000000190235804075","color":"BLACK","size":"S","on_sale":false,"quantity":"31","original_price":35,"price":35},{"upc":"00000000190235804082","color":"BLACK","size":"M","on_sale":false,"quantity":"67","original_price":35,"price":35},{"upc":"00000000190235804099","color":"BLACK","size":"L","on_sale":false,"quantity":"80","original_price":35,"price":35},{"upc":"00000000190235804105","color":"BLACK","size":"XL","on_sale":false,"quantity":"33","original_price":35,"price":35},{"upc":"00000000190235804112","color":"BLACK","size":"XXL","on_sale":false,"quantity":"3","original_price":35,"price":35}]}
```

Comment: The text you are trying to parse almost looks like a valid JSON/Python dictionary. Why are you trying to use regex string matching instead of converting it to an actual data-structure?

Comment: @DeepSpace Can you elaborate your answer as i'm just a starter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches here:

(Better) **Non-Regex approach**

The "text" you are trying to match looks (almost) like a valid JSON object / Python dictionary (except for some extra parentheses and the `HOLIDAY` part which may originate from bad copy-pasting).

Use this fact to convert it to an object then just grab the top-level `'quantity'` key:

```
d = {'category_path': ['Mens', 'Tees'],
     'colors': ['BLACK'],
     'created': '2018-12-01',
     'modified': '2018-12-20',
     'on_sale': 'false',
     'original_price': 35,
     'price': 35,
     'quantity': '214',
     'sizes': ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL'],
     'upcs': ['00000000190235804075',
      '00000000190235804082',
      '00000000190235804099',
      '00000000190235804105',
      '00000000190235804112'],
     'variations': [{'color': 'BLACK',
                     'on_sale': 'false',
                     'original_price': 35,
                     'price': 35,
                     'quantity': '31',
                     'size': 'S',
                     'upc': '00000000190235804075'},
                     ...,
                     {'color': 'BLACK',
                     'on_sale': 'false',
                     'original_price': 35,
                     'price': 35,
                     'quantity': '3',
                     'size': 'XXL',
                     'upc': '00000000190235804112'}]}

print(d['quantity'])
# 214
```

(Last resort) **Regex approach**

If you insist, you can use `re.search` which by default stops at the first match as written in its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.search):

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match

```
import re

text = """ ({{ HOLIDAY","on_sale":false,"quantity":"214","original_price":35,"price":35,"category_path":["Mens","Tees"],"created":"2018-12-01","modified":"2018-12-20","colors":["BLACK"],"sizes":["S","M","L","XL","XXL"],"upcs":["00000000190235804075","00000000190235804082","00000000190235804099","00000000190235804105","00000000190235804112"],"variations":[{"upc":"00000000190235804075","color":"BLACK","size":"S","on_sale":false,"quantity":"31","original_price":35,"price":35},{"upc":"00000000190235804082","color":"BLACK","size":"M","on_sale":false,"quantity":"67","original_price":35,"price":35},{"upc":"00000000190235804099","color":"BLACK","size":"L","on_sale":false,"quantity":"80","original_price":35,"price":35},{"upc":"00000000190235804105","color":"BLACK","size":"XL","on_sale":false,"quantity":"33","original_price":35,"price":35},{"upc":"00000000190235804112","color":"BLACK","size":"XXL","on_sale":false,"quantity":"3","original_price":35,"price":35}]}"""

print(re.search(r'"quantity":"(.*?)"', text).group(1))
# 214
```

Comment: Using regex what is the alternative way to make it non-greedy? As i already know using `[0]` will give me first occurrence and also `re_first` would do that. but using regex elements is it possible?

Comment: @SumitKumarMallick I updated the regex solution to use `search`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
"quantity":"(.*?)".*
```